# How to prevent replacing previous data in XML files

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am creating a sample login form in a windows forms application & I am trying to save my login username or password in a XML file but when I submit username or password it replaces the previous entry.

What I want is that when I submit username or password it should be appended into the same XML file but don't replace any previous entry.

Like:

```
<Table>
  <Entry>
    <User>first_user1@gmail.com</User> 
    <Password>*********</Password> 
  </Entry>
</Table>

<Table>
  <Entry>
    <User>second_user2@gmail.com</User> 
    <Password>*********</Password> 
  </Entry>
</Table>
```

But its replacing the first enty every time and not giving the space for second entry

Please give me solution for this

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("entry.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;
        writer.WriteStartElement("Table");
        createNode(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, writer);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("XML File created ! ");
```

}

```
private void createNode(string pName, string pPass, XmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Entry");
    writer.WriteStartElement("User");
    writer.WriteString(pName);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Password");
    writer.WriteString(pPass);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ To XML. It's much more flexible:

```
private void AddEntry(XElement xml, string user, string password)
{
    xml.Add(new XElement("Entry",
                         new XElement("User", user),
                         new XElement("Password", password)));
}
```

and then

```
XElement x = XElement.Load("In.xml");
AddEntry(x, "newuser", "newpassword");
x.Save("In.xml");
```

So, if your file was:

```
<Table>
  <Entry>
    <User>first_user1@gmail.com</User>
    <Password>*********</Password>
  </Entry>
</Table>
```

you get an output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Table>
  <Entry>
    <User>first_user1@gmail.com</User>
    <Password>*********</Password>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <User>newuser</User>
    <Password>newpassword</Password>
  </Entry>
</Table>
```

Comment: using ur code i am getting this error

"The type or namespace name 'XElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @user1687470 add the following: using System.Xml.Linq;. Your project must be at least on .Net3.5